# XSS and CSRF - basic difference

Tags: xss, csrf

While the whole method of XSS and CSRF attacks are totally different, the main difference is that:

XSS - Runs a Script on the brwoser

CSRF - Sends a (HTTP) request from the browser.

Is correct (a Yes or No answer will suffice)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. The XSS (Cross Site Scripting) try to execute in some way a script on victim's browser. It can be reflected, stored, etc.

The CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) try to use a victim's already logged cookie/session to perform any action on a web.

References:

- [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
- [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if that was the basic difference or if I totally misunderstood the concept.